# Does "grim" share an etymology with the surname "Grimm"?

Tags: etymology

People have often punned about Grimm's fairy tales being very grim. For example, TV Tropes has the trope [Grimmification](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Grimmification) about tales being made more grim. (The Brothers Grimm didn't engage in Grimmification - they didn't need to. In fact, they [Disneyfied](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Disneyfication).)

Are the two words "grim" and "Grimm" etymologically related?

The English edition of Wiktionary does not have an entry for "Grimm", nor does the Online Etymology Dictionary.

Wiktionary states that [grim](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grim) came from Old English, which came from Germanic. And Grimm is used as a surname in Germany.

[Grimm](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Grimm) has an entry in the German Wiktionary, but even with Google translate I can't tell if it's talking about a name, a noun, or both.

One person I talked to about this said that "Grimm" meant "hooded", which would explain "The Grim Reaper" (apart from it only have one "m"). Is that true?

Comment: If you think the Grimms Disneyfied, you've probably been reading Disneyfied Grimm. Their actual stories are pretty  -- well, grim.

Comment: @gmcgath TV Tropes' Disneyfication page actually states that the Brothers Grimm Disneyfied.

Comment: I wasn't disputing that such a claim exists on the Web, only that it's true.

Comment: So, like, it's a coincidence? ;-)

Comment: I realize that I'm reviving an old thread but since I studied the Grimm Märchen / fairy tales in grad school, I can add some information, though I don't have sources available any longer.

Comment: The Grimm brothers traveled pretty extensively collecting the folk tales now known as fairy tales (in English) or Märchen (in German). They published them for an adult audience, and later after finding out how popular they were among children later decided to republish them because, in their opinion they weren't suitable for children. Their second and subsequent publications were all "Disney-fied", relatively speaking,and the versions we now know as the Grimm fairy tales are from their later printings. The true originals were actually still scarier and more gruesome.

Comment: Standards for what is child appropriate have changed over time, now that children aren't generally involved in slaughtering food animals we can afford to be somewhat more sensitive :-)

Answer (score 6):

It is clear that Old English *grimm* is cognate with Ger *grimm(ig)*; Koebler [Althochdeutscheswörterbuch](http://www.koeblergerhard.de/germanistischewoerterbuecher/althochdeutscheswoerterbuch/ahdG.pdf)) refers this to Pokorny ([Indo-European Etymological Dictionary](http://dnghu.org/indoeuropean.html)) 458, where it is derived from PIE root **ghrem-2*, “heavy sound, thunder, **grumble**”.

However, Koebler also notes a similar word, *grimo*, “helmet, mask”, which I imagine is what your informant who suggested “hooded” was referring to; it’s cognate with OE and Icelandic *grima*, from which Tolkien took the name of the evil counsellor Grima Wormtongue. Pokorny 457 derives these from PIE root **ghrēi-*, **ghrəi-*, **ghrī-*, **ghrei-*, “smear”, from which he also derives Middle Low German *grimet*, “black-streaked”, and *grēme* “smut”, which appear to be cognate with English *grime*.

Both roots were used in mediaeval personal names. Genealogical sites derive the modern surname variously from both; but they do not cite authorities and may safely be ignored.

Unless an authority can be found which definitively traces the Brothers' surname, I think the verdict must be Not Proven.

Answer (score 3):

Well, we once spelled *grim* with two *m*’s in English, as *grimm*. The OED gives the etymology of *grim* as:

> OE.  *grim(m)* = OFris.  *grim,* OS.  *grim* (Dutch grim), OHG. and MHG.  *grim*
>   (G.  *grimm*), ONor.  *grimmr* (Sw.  *grym* harsh, Da.  *grim* ugly).  Ormin
>   employs a disyllabic form *grimme*, corresponding to OHG.  *grimmi*, MHG.
>   *grimme*.  The OTeut. root **grem-* is an ablaut-variant of **gram-*; see **grame** *a*.

So it would seem the same word.

What I find fascinating is the hidden gem that *grim* is ultimately an ablaut variant of a *gram-* word, which makes me think of *grammar* and linguistics, which makes me think of ***Grimm’s* Law**.

Comment: Makes me think of *grimoire*.

Comment: @KitFox And then to *glamours*, perhaps.

Comment: What's a "gram-word"?

Comment: *Grammar* is from Greek *graphô* "write", as you well known. Dutch *gram* means "wrath".

Comment: Alas, Pokorny derives *graph-* and *gramma-* from PIE *\*gherebh-*, "scratch, write".

Comment: Makes me think of _grampa_. He shore had a legendary temper.

Answer (score 3):

The noun "Grimm" in German means "fury," which suggests a connection though there's been a drift in meaning in one language or both. If "grimm" means hooded in any language, it isn't German.

Comment: There is an obsolete noun *grim* in English which per the OED means “Grimness, fury, rage.”

Answer (score 2):

They both come from the same PIE root, according to the *AHD of PIE Roots*.

> ****gʰrem-*** Angry.
>     1a. *grim*, from OE *grimm* 'fierce, severe'
>     1b. *grimace*, from OF
>      (Both a and b from Gmc **grimma*)
>     2. *grumble*, from Gmc **grum*
>     3. *pogrom*, from Russian *grom* 'thunder'

As gmcgath has pointed out, *Grimm* means 'fury' in German, so -- insofar as proper names can have meanings, it pretty much has to come from this root too.